# Reemplazar todas los caracteres en python

Tags: python

tengo esto, opcionRandom es una palabra y quisiera reemplazar todos los caracteres por * sin embargo solo reemplaza algunos caracteres y no todos, que podria hacer?

```
for letra in opcionRandom:
    palabraReemplazada = opcionRandom.replace(letra, '*')

print(palabraReemplazada)
```

Comment: No se lo que quieres hacer, pero tal y cómo está solo va a replazar la última letra. Usa algo más simple, algo cómo `palabraReemplazada = "*" * len(opcionRandom)` y te ahorras el ciclo `for`. Alternativamente para que funcione tu código antes del ciclo `for` inicializa `palabraReemplazada=opcionRandom` y modifica el interior del ciclo a `palabraReemplazada = palabraReemplazada.replace(letra, '*')`. De cualquier manera, la manera que expones no es para nada el mejor acercamiento.

Comment: Además, la propuesta de Jaime, a diferencia de tu código, no recorre la cadena varias veces.